# Passing sorted data as json object in laravel controller, but response automatically sorts it by value

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I know there are a lot of related questions already been asked here, but honestly none of the solutions worked for me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I fetched data from database using laravel Elequent. I used sortBy to sort the data. I have used dd to check the data is perfectly sorted. But when return this data as json object, and then retrieve it in ajax response, then i get the data automatically sorted by value. I mean the order totally changed.

Comment: Sorted by value? Is the order/sorting that important? How do you debug?

Comment: Yes i need to fetch sorted record by particular column. but i am unable to retrieve the record in in ajax response in same order as i am sending from controller.